# Image inside tableViewCell automatically zooms when touched, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have no idea why, but when I touch a cell, image inside it kind of zooms and is partially of screen. Below you can see, the first row looks like it should and the second row was selected and now looks zoomed.
[image]
There is not much code, only ViewController and TableViewCell that both have minimum required code.

EDIT: Here's how I add cells, and there is no didSelectAtRow.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCell
    
    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: "uk.png")
    
    return cell
}
```

EDIT2: Initially my imageView constrains where 0 to all margins, so that whole cell would be only image. When I made image quite small, none of zooming happens, so maybe I am doing something wrong with constrains?

**Final Edit - Problem Solved**
Not sure, how that zooming happened, but in my case trying different constrains solved the problem.

Comment: can you show your didselect row and cellforrowatIndex method

Comment: What is the content mode if the imageview?

Comment: Sorry, what? Content (of TableViewCell) mode is Center.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your tableview is reuse its cell

First set the constraints of the cell. 
and
also implement the 
the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath with

```
if(cell == nil)
{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

}
```

also share your code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath